# Заполнение RecyclerView c TextWatcher

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, он состоит из `EditText`-ов. Если в адаптер передать пустой список, то адаптер автоматически добавит в него пустую строку. Идея в том, что при вводе в `EditText` (отслушиваю изменения при помощи `TextWatcher`) сразу добавляется пустой `EditText`, то есть в `RecyclerView` всегда есть один пустой `EditText`. Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что адаптер не работает, когда ему передаешь не пустой список.

**Log ошибки:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{bbd27c2 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0800df app:id/recyclerView}, adapter:com.example.arraylist.SubtaskAdapter@3b339d3, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@b201910, context:com.example.arraylist.AddActivity@925d94c
        at com.example.arraylist.SubtaskAdapter$CustomEditTextListener.onTextChanged(SubtaskAdapter.java:114)
        at com.example.arraylist.SubtaskAdapter$SubtasksViewHolder.bind(SubtaskAdapter.java:88)
        at com.example.arraylist.SubtaskAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SubtaskAdapter.java:40)
        at com.example.arraylist.SubtaskAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SubtaskAdapter.java:17)
```

**SubstaksAdapter:**

```
public class SubtaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubtaskAdapter.SubtasksViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> elements;

    public SubtaskAdapter(ArrayList<String> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubtasksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.subtask_edittext;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(LayoutIdForListItem, parent, false);
        return new SubtasksViewHolder(view, new CustomEditTextListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubtasksViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    class SubtasksViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText editText;
        ImageButton imageButton;
        CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener;

        public SubtasksViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.customEditTextListener = customEditTextListener;
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            imageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(customEditTextListener);
        }

        void bind(final int position) {
            if (elements.size() > 1)
                editText.setHint("Cледующий шаг");
            else
                editText.setHint("Добавьте шаг");

            if (elements.get(position).equals(""))
                imageButton.setEnabled(false);
            else
                imageButton.setEnabled(true);

            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    elements.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            
            customEditTextListener.updatePosition(getAdapterPosition());
            editText.setText(elements.get(position));
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        }
    }

    class CustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {

        int position;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            elements.set(position, s.toString());
            if (!elements.get(elements.size() - 1).equals("")) {
                elements.add("");
                updatePosition(position);
                SubtaskAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в моем случае, надо было, чтобы список, скармливаемый адаптеру, всегда заканчивался элементом с пустой строкой. С этим условие всё работает корректно.

Comment: Не понятно, как ваш комментарий вдруг оказался ответом, да еще и решением.

Answer (score 1):

*Этот пост просто "вытяжка" из [ответа на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069171), поэтому и является общим.*

В Вашем случае ошибка находится здесь:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubtasksViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}
```

В методе `bind()` Вы устанавливаете слушатель на нажатие кнопки, который должен будет инициировать повторный вызов `onBindViewHolder` (`bind()` находится в `onBindViewHolder`), что и является основанием для возникновения этой ошибки.

Решение: перенесите назначение слушателя в `ViewHolder`. Подробнее в [источнике](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069171).

Comment: ознакомился с ответом на англоязычном SO, но так и не понял, что мне сделать.

Comment: Возможно, вы не до конца поняли принцип работы моего приложения. **1.** `RecyclerView` состоит из `editText` элементов. **2.** За каждым из них закреплен `TextWatcher`, который, при вводе каких-либо символов, добавляет в `RecyclerView` новый `EditText`. **3.** Я думаю, что проблема в том, что я скармливаю сразу много элементов. То есть я добавил один элемент, за ним еще. А параллельно `TextWatcher` тоже добавляет элементы. **Итог:** надо сделать, чтобы сначала добавились все переданные `EditText`-ы, и только после этого начали работать `TextWatcher`-ы